# I am tyring to fadeIn and fadeOut css background color with jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am trying to fadeIn a background color in the beforeSend and fadeOut in the success with ajax. I don't know what I have done wrong. Help, please.

```js
var data={
 action: 'tag_user_update',
 postSearchNonce : MyAjaxSearch.postSearchNonce,
 tag : $(this).closest("a").text(),
 users_id : $("#users_id").val()
}

$.ajax({
 url: MyAjaxSearch.ajaxurl,
 type:'POST',
 cache: false,
 data:data,
 beforeSend: function() {
  $('.tag_link').animate({ backgroundColor:'yellow'},'slow');
 },
 success: function(data){
  $('.tag_link').animate({ backgroundColor:'white'},'slow');
 }
});//ajax
```

Comment: I belive color animation is part of jquery UI (https://jqueryui.com/animate/) so make sure you have that included.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your ajax methods follow this structure $.ajax({}).done({}) or $.ajax({}).success({}). You've included the callback function .success() within the .ajax({}) request.

As you can see in the example below, .done() is not contained within the .ajax() call. .success() should not be internal either. done() and .success() are both callback functions that happen after your ajax() request. Also, .success() is being deprecated, so .done() has the same effect in the example below

from http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://fiddle.jshell.net/favicon.png",
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    xhr.overrideMimeType( "text/plain; charset=x-user-defined" );
    }
})
.done(function( data ) {
   if ( console && console.log ) {
   console.log( "Sample of data:", data.slice( 0, 100 ) );
   }
});
```